# How to find length of total completed items?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angular5

**How to find length of total completed items?**

how to find total completed items (todos)? in items list 
how to find a length of a certain object in array

```
<div>Todo List:</div> {{(items | async)?.length}}  <-- Total Items in list

<div>{{(items.completed | async)?.length}}</div> <!-- Total completed items? - length of total completed items

<hr>

<ul *ngIf="todo_all">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async"  [class.completed]="item.completed">
        {{item.description}}
    </li>
</ul>


itemsRef: AngularFireList;
items: Observable<Todo[]>;

constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
this.itemsRef = db.list('todos')
// Use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can actually either filter the items you have on the client from the existing observable or make the simple query to fetch just the completed ones.

```
completedItemsCount: Observable<number>;
```

One way:

```
this.completedItemsCount = items
.map(items => 
    items.filter(item => item.completed).length
); // Maps the observable, filters the completed and return its length
```

Another way:

```
this.completedItemsCount = db
.list('/todos', ref => ref.orderByChild('completed').equalTo(true))
.map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => (
        { 
            key: c.payload.key,
            ...c.payload.val(),
        }
    )).length; // Eventually return the length
});
```

Of course it's always better if you could persist the counter somewhere in the database so you wouldn't have to get the whole list first just for a number, but still this will probably work great, unless your todo lists are really really huge. If they are, it's gonna be taking quite a lot of time to appear the number for the first time. I hope this helps.